# bootstrap 5 popover with html content

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to get separate the bootstrap5 popover content from the HTML attributes like you can do with other components, but I can't get it to work.

```js
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function(popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
})
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="popover">Click to toggle popover</a>
<div id="customdiv" style="display: none">
  <h1> popover </h1>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 13):

Nobody answered properly with **simple JavaScript** without jQuery dependency. It's important because Bootstrap 5 doesn't depend on jQuery anymore.

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-link" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-content-id="popover-content" tabindex="0" role="button">
  Open Popover
</a>

<div id="popover-content" class="d-none">
  Popover content with <strong>HTML</strong>.
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
const list = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
list.map((el) => {
  let opts = {
    animation: false,
  }
  if (el.hasAttribute('data-bs-content-id')) {
    opts.content = document.getElementById(el.getAttribute('data-bs-content-id')).innerHTML;
    opts.html = true;
  }
  new bootstrap.Popover(el, opts);
})
```

Answer (score 12):

```
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl,{html: true})
});
```

Comment: Can't make it work on bootstrap 5. Does this solution require bootstrap 5.2?

Answer (score 5):

None of the answers really offered me a complete solution where the popover does not appear until the `data-bs-trigger` event happen so this is my solution:

Element that when hovering on will have popover:

```html
<a class="btn btn-question-tag" 
   data-bs-toggle="popover" 
   data-bs-trigger="hover focus" 
   data-content-id="popover-27" 
   href="#">
element to trigger popover
</a>
```

Element that its inner html will be in the popover that appears.

```html
<div style="display: none;" id="popover-27">
    <div class="popover" role="tooltip">
      This is the 
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```js
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'));
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
    const popoverId = popoverTriggerEl.attributes['data-content-id'];
    if (popoverId) {
        const contentEl=$(`#${popoverId.value}`).html();
        return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl, {
            content: contentEl,
            html: true,
        });
    }else{//do something else cause data-content-id isn't there.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

***There is a simple way to put an html element in popover container***

you must put the html element directly in data-bs-content tag,
and set the data-bs-html="true" to parse that content as html
and also disable the sanitize to make the content readable as html

this code works for me try it too.

```js
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function(popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
})
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="popover"
data-bs-html="true" data-bs-sanitize="false"
data-bs-content='<div class="popover fs-6" role="tooltip">
 <div class="popover-body">Providing your birthday helps make sure you get the right Facebook experience for your age. If you want to change who sees this, go to the About section of your profile. For more details, please visit our <a href="#"> Data Policy</a>.</div></div>'>Click to toggle popover</a>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Simple and effective solution! This works for me on plain boostrap 5, does not require jQuery, and does not require to give the popover content an explicit id.

Comment: This is the current correct answer.

Comment: This is correct but for anyone else wondering why their equivalent of the above doesn't work, **jospert** has used single quotes for the `data-bs-html=''` rather than double!

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap v5.2.0 and laravel 8 in app.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 var element = document.getElementById('myPopover');
 if (element) {
     var popover = new bootstrap.Popover(element, {
         container: 'body',
         html: true,
         content: function() {
             return document.getElementById('popover-content').innerHTML;
         },
     });
 }
});
```

Laravel blade

```
                  <a tabindex="0" type="button" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="bottom" aria-label="Share this article socially" id="myPopover" >
                                   <img src="{{asset('layout/icon_return.svg')}}" alt="share icon">
                               </a>
   
   
                               <div class="pop-in" id="popover-content" style="display:none;"> <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
                                       <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="First group">
                                           <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={{ $item->url }}" target="_blank" rel="noopener" type="button" ><img src="{{asset('layout/facebook.svg')}}" alt="Share Page on Facebook" ></a>
                                           <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url={{ $item->url }}%2F&text={{ $item->title }}.&hashtags=css,html" target="_blank" rel="noopener" type="button" ><img src="{{asset('layout/twitter.svg')}}" alt="Share Page on Twitter"></a>
                                           <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={{ $item->url }}%2F&item={{ $item->title }}" target="_blank" rel="noopener" type="button" ><img src="{{asset('layout/linkedin.svg')}}" alt="Share Page on LinkedIn" ></a>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>
                               </div>
```

Comment: you can keep popover content in template tag than no need to add extra display:none inline style. it will be hidden anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```html
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
})
var popover = new bootstrap.Popover(document.querySelector('.element'), {
        trigger: 'hover',
        html: true,
        content:function () {
            return '<label>Test</label>';
        },
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Although the above answers looks fine but there is small correction here. **Content** option in bootstrap 5 is not working with innerHTML as it expects the type `element/string/function` to get the content from.

So as usual, first we will need to create div for the content with some id and then wrap it inside hidden div as this will be also shown in main flow. And then with `html` and `content` options provided by bootstrap popover, we will insert the custom popover content.

Also, instead of innerHTML, we will directly have `document.getElementById('mypopover-content')` as the popover content element to show as the content (and not `document.getElementById('mypopover-content').innerHTML`).

```js
var popover = new bootstrap.Popover(document.querySelector('.example-popover'), {
  container: 'body',
  html: true,
  content: document.getElementById('mypopover-content'),
})
```

```css
body {
margin: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<a class="btn btn-primary example-popover" role="button" tabindex="0"  title="Content demonstration popover"
>Trigger popover with other html content</a>

<div hidden>
  <div id="mypopover-content">
    <p>This is the custom popover html content that should be inserted into my example popover</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">and the button as well</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var hideDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('hide')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden'
var popoverBtn = document.getElementById('btn-action')
var popover = new bootstrap.Popover(popoverBtn, {
    placement: 'bottom',
    html: true,
    content: function() {
        return document.getElementById('id-content-div');
    }

})
   var showDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('hide')[0].style.visibility = 'visible'
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" id="btn-action">Click to toggle popover</a>
<div id="id-content-div" class="hide">
  <h1> popover </h1>
  <p>Hello popover world</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Explaining the suggested change is going to be helpful for everyone.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(function() {
var options = {
    html: true,
    title: "Optional: HELLO(Will overide the default-the inline title)",
    //html element
    content: $("#popover-content")
    //Doing below won't work. Shows title only
    //content: $("#popover-content").html()

  }
  var exampleEl = document.getElementById('example')
  var popover = new bootstrap.Popover(exampleEl, options)
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="popover-content">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Search" name="search">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
        <i class="bi bi-search"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
  <button class="btn btn-success m-3">Button</button>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" placeholder="Button red">
</div>

<a id="example" tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-bs-toggle="popover" title="Default: Html inside popover" data-bs-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right? This is default, but Can be empty">Html inside popover</a>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can't have a zero length title and content. From the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/popovers/#overview)...

> "Zero-length title and content values will never show a popover."

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger"
        data-bs-toggle="popover"
        data-bs-title="Hello">Click to toggle popover</a>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/QoNCWlZORs)

Comment: The default value of title if title attribute isn't present is empty string, so there is no need to use it. It is mentioned in BS5 popover options https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/popovers/#options

Comment: Yes thanks! Still a title or content is needed to get it to work.

Comment: that's not true. you can get it to work without the title

Comment: To your own demo, change your data-bs-title to data-bs-content. It works without the title, like I said. You have to either have a title or a content.

Comment: Yes, that's EXACTLY what my comment to the OP says.... "title or content" .. my answer is referencing the Bootstrap docs ... why did you downvote it?