# Using nested HTML in an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

So lately I've been trying to learn a bit more about nested usage of HTML in Bootstrap.

Whilst following a guide on the usage of Popovers I've came across this;

```
<button
  id="btn3"
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-primary show"
  data-bs-toggle="popover"
  data-bs-trigger="focus"
  title="<h1><a href='#btn2'class ='btn btn-danger' onclick='innerFunc()' type='button' id='btnInner' data-bs-toggle='btn2'>click me</a> title</h1>"
  data-bs-content="content"
  data-bs-html="true"
>
  Popover!
</button>
```

I'm trying to reach this inner **`<a>`** tag by it's given id.

When I reference this in my Javascript it returns a **null** object to the console.

Is there any way of reaching this nested object?
If so can i hold a reference to it in a variable for further use?

Comment: The code shown above does not contain an _element_, it only contains HTML in string form inside the `title` property. You will need to go and look into how these bootstrap popovers work, to find the point _when_ this gets transformed into an actual HTML element to be displayed. (It only adds the elements to the DOM when the popover gets shown, once it gets hidden again, the element is also removed from the DOM again.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While researching deeper into the subject I came across this post;

[Bootstrap 5 popover with html content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66899307/bootstrap-5-popover-with-html-content)

In this thread the answer provided by [Gregory Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14000587/gregory-michael) gave me an answer. Apparently the options you pass via Javascript are overridden by the HTML content of the DOM object so in order to dynamically change this object you would have to pass the custom HTML in the specified object creating a separate object and overriding the other one.

Thank you [@CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) for your suggestion. ^^

Answer (score -1):

you can't put html inside an attribute, you have to follow popover rules from bootstrap

[Bootstrap Popover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/popovers/)

Otherwise you can add custom html through JS without Bootstrap

```
const popover = document.querySelector('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
```

After that you can tweak and add some html to the element.

Comment: I'm not really an expert but the inner `<a>` tag works when pointing with href to another element, this other button is also a popover example button and it produces a popover on focus. I will try this method too to see if it produces the results I want. ^^